# gmapping and inversion Hokuyo don't work

Tags: navigation, hokuyo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm trying to use the hokuyo on my robot, from upside down. (inverted position)

On Rviz all frames are correct and I see the the laser points perfect (rotated), but gmapping is ignoring the fact of my transformation:
`<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_base_laser_link" args="0.058 0 0.125 0.0 0.0 3.1416 /base_link /base_laser_link 100" />`

and the mapping is not coherent with what hokuyo senses. As i like show on next images, can someone help-me? (I can't implement slam this way)

( I have tried with `<param name="inverted_laser" value="false" />`, with `<param name="inverted_laser" value="true" />` and without parameter and is the same) I'm using electric version, after images you can see my launch files.

[image description http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-4.png](http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-4.png)
[image description http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-5.png](http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-5.png)
[image description http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-6.png](http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-6.png)
[image description http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-7.png](http://fbnsantos.com/Download/Screenshot-7.png)

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="hokuyo_node" type="hokuyo_node" name="laser_scan">
    <param name="port" value="/dev/ttyACM0"/>
    <param name="frame_id" value="base_laser_link"/>
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan" />
  </node>
  <node name="filbotic" pkg="filbotic" type="filbotic_driver" output="screen" >
    <param name="port_name" value="/dev/ttyUSB0" />
  </node>
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_base_laser_link" args="0.058 0 0.125 0.0 0.0 3.1416 /base_link /base_laser_link 100" />
  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_footprint_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0  /base_footprint /base_link 100" />
</launch>    `


<launch>
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="gmapping" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="base_scan" />
    <param name="inverted_laser" value="false" />
    <param name="maxUrange" value="30.0" />
    <param name="particles" value="30" />
    <param name="delta" value="0.01" />
    <param name="xmin" value="-15.0" />
    <param name="xmax" value="15.0" />
    <param name="ymin" value="-15.0" />
    <param name="ymax" value="15.0" />
    <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5" />
    <param name="linearUpdate" value="1.0" />
    <param name="map_update_interval" value="1.0" />
    <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.3" />
    <param name="llsamplerange" value ="0.05" />
    <param name="llsamplestep" value ="0.05" />
    <param name="lasamplerange" value ="0.05" />
    <param name="lasamplestep" value ="0.05" />
  </node>
</launch>             `
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12630/gmapping-and-inversion-hokuyo-don%27t-work/) by [Filipe Santos](https://answers.ros.org/users/907/filipe-santos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 346 on 2012-01-13

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JeffRousseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/75/jeffrousseau/) on 2012-01-13**:
I ran into this back in Diamondback--Since I had the same problem and hokuyo_node does NOT support an inverted parameter like the SICK node does, I cheated and wrote a quick and dirty node that flipped my scans.  I could have sworn someone updated gmapping to support transforms in electric though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could you provide a bag-file of a short drive around? (1-2 minutes or so)

Gmapping has indeed support for transforms, but i think they missed some essential parts. To solve your problem i suggest the following:

- Check out the gmapping sources from [here](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/slam_gmapping/trunk/gmapping/)
- Apply some parts of [this proposed patch](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5250) which has been discussed [in this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/2918/gmapping-and-inverted-upside-down-laser#4656):

```
This is only one part of the solution! Look at the linked patch file from the edit!
Change line 340 of src/slam_gmapping.cpp:
from:
  gsp_laser_angle_increment_ = scan.angle_increment;
to:
  gsp_laser_angle_increment_ = angle_min > angle_max ? -fabs(scan.angle_increment) : fabs(scan.angle_increment);
```

- Compile gmapping and test again.

If i am right, that should do the trick. It would still be nice if you could create a bag file, so that we have an actual usecase for testing a patch.

Regards, Ben

---

EDIT (20.01.2012): Sadly the changes above are incomplete and make the result even worse. Based on the new bag-file and two bag files i had from other robots i have now written a patch, that should hopefully work for every constellation of CW, CCW and/or inverted scanners. I have uploaded the patch [here](http://users.informatik.haw-hamburg.de/%7Eaba879/ros/gmapping_inverted_laser_new.patch). If i get some positive feedback, i will also submit the patch to the [bug rebort from arebgun](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5250).

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2014-07-16**:
So what's the final patch in this whole saga? And does it work for all possible permutations and combinations? Thank you for taking the trouble :)

PS - Why hasn't it been incorporated into the gmapping source code by now?